# Asphalt career performance isn't synced between my PC and Android phone

Tags: applications, windows, data-transfer

I am playing asphalt 8 airbone on my pc which runs on windows 8.1 pro and on my android smartphone. I connected Asphalt 8 with my same facebook account but it doesn't show same career performance, my car pack, etc. Help me out with this.

Comment: Does the game offer cross platform saves? It might be worth asking the developer. Is there cloud saving, any option in game to import a save from the cloud? I doubt it does to be honest, but worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Ryan from Gameloft, writing on the Touch Arcade iOS forum](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?s=6c81989f3711cf688b6c4d06f2784ead&p=2944230&postcount=178), Asphalt 8: Airborne doesn't sync save games between different platforms:-

> no, Asphalt 8 doesn't have cross-platform save functions. You won't be able to play on an iOS device and then load that progress on an Android device.

He's writing about iOS and Android, but it's easy to see why the same would apply to Android and Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

Both are being played on different platforms and machines. Whenever you are playing the game from your PC, the player-specific data would probably come somewhere from `Users` directory in your `C` drive, however, for your mobile, it will be stored on your mobile storage in a specific folder. You won't be able to see the same progress since those details are stored locally on the respective storage drives and doesn't get fetched online.